# Excitation current calculation for alternator

Tags: voltage-regulator, alternator

I have an old brush alternator where field excitation happens in the stator. Unfortunately no information is given about the required field excitation current.

The alternator is rated 3 Phase, 400V, 11.5A. The field winding has a resistance of 8 Ohm.

Given these specifications, please help to find a suitable automatic voltage regulator. What maximum current should an AVR be capable to deliver?

Comment: The impedance of the field winding might be good to know.

Comment: Added to the alternator characteristics.

Comment: Have you searched using the name of the manufacturer? It might help to know if the machine was designed for military or ship use. There is nothing that can be determined directly form the output ratings except that it is likely a 50 Hz machine. You will probably need to perform open-circuit and short-circuit tests. You can use a simple adjustable-voltage power supply for that. What you will apparently need is a  static exciter, not just an AVR.

Comment: @CharlesCowie this thing is about 50 years old. There is no more information about that. What do you mean by static exciter? It has 9-10v residual voltage when spinning at 1500 revs.

Comment: A static exciter is essentially a variable power supply that is controlled by an AVR. With most synchronous generators, excitation power is generated by the machine in some way. A static exciter has some kind of external supply from the grid or a battery. An AVR may just have the regulator function and require some kind of external power supply. You can look at the details of modern AVRs and see what is available, but there may be nothing suitable to just connect and run an unusual old machine.

Comment: @charlescowie I already had a modern AVR connected which biilt up power from the residual voltage. But it did not deliver enough current. That's why I want to know the required current to properly select the required AVR.

Comment: You need to determine if the AVR is limiting the current to protect itself, reaching its maximum voltage without producing the maximum current, or limiting the current to regulate the voltage. What other useful information have you neglected to put in the question?

Comment: @CharlesCowie the AVR I used got toasted so obviously it didn't protect itself enough. Therefore I need the information to properly seize a new one.